# How to fix "Invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame?

Tags: r

> Error in `dimnames<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = list(n)) :
> `invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame

That error occurs when I run the following code below

```
explanation <- lime::explain(
(test), 
explainer    = explainer, 
n_labels     = 1, 
n_features   = 4,
kernel_width = 0.5)
```

test is a dataframe with 10 rows and 35 columns with numbers type num.

explainer is

```
 explainer <- lime::lime(
x              = x_train_tbl, 
model          = model_keras, 
bin_continuous = FALSE)
```

which when printed spits out summary statistics for each attribute

Comment: Can you provide the output of `str(test)` and `str(x_train_tbl)`

Comment: For str(test)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ SeniorCitizen                        : num  -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 ...
etc

Comment: for Str(x_train_tbl) Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5626 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ SeniorCitizen                        : num  -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 -0.434 ...

Comment: It's much easier to work with your data if you [edit] it into the question, not comments