# invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame when using lime on a keras CNN model in R

Tags: r, keras, lime

I am having the same error as [How to fix "Invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58572612/how-to-fix-invalid-dimnames-given-for-data-frame) when usin lime package in R

> Error in `dimnames<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = list(n)) :
> invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame

I am trying to apply the lime function (explain) to a keras CNN network

```
Model
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                                       Output Shape                                               Param #                
=====================================================================================================
conv1d_8 (Conv1D)                                                  (None, 1896, 64)                                           384                    
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNormalization)                         (None, 1896, 64)                                           256                    
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_8 (LeakyReLU)                                          (None, 1896, 64)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)                                               (None, 1896, 64)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_9 (Conv1D)                                                  (None, 1886, 32)                                           22560                  
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNormalization)                         (None, 1886, 32)                                           128                    
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_9 (LeakyReLU)                                          (None, 1886, 32)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)                                               (None, 1886, 32)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_10 (Conv1D)                                                 (None, 1866, 16)                                           10768                  
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNormalization)                        (None, 1866, 16)                                           64                     
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_10 (LeakyReLU)                                         (None, 1866, 16)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_12 (Dropout)                                               (None, 1866, 16)                                           0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_11 (Conv1D)                                                 (None, 1826, 8)                                            5256                   
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNormalization)                        (None, 1826, 8)                                            32                     
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_11 (LeakyReLU)                                         (None, 1826, 8)                                            0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_13 (Dropout)                                               (None, 1826, 8)                                            0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)                                                (None, 14608)                                              0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                                                    (None, 100)                                                1460900                
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_14 (Dropout)                                               (None, 100)                                                0                      
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                                                    (None, 5)                                                  505                    
=====================================================================================================================================================
Total params: 1,500,853
Trainable params: 1,500,613
Non-trainable params: 240
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

```
my_explainer <- lime(x =train, model = model, bin_continuous = FALSE)

explanation <- explain(test, explainer = my_explainer, n_labels = 1, n_features = 2, kernel_width = 0.5)
```

My train and test sets contain 1900 features, here I display only 9 to simplify

```
str(train[,1:9])
'data.frame':   77 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ X1: num  0.005598 0.009835 0.005365 0.000725 0.000992 ...
 $ X2: num  0 0.00156 0 0.00172 0.00261 ...
 $ X3: num  0 0.00752 0 0 0.00556 ...
 $ X4: num  0 0.00191 0.00479 0.00193 0.005 ...
 $ X5: num  0.0028 0.0033 0 0.00115 0.00503 ...
 $ X6: num  0 0 0 0.000453 0.00258 ...
 $ X7: num  0 0.00121 0 0.00127 0.00185 ...
 $ X8: num  0.00646 0 0.0097 0.00435 0.00278 ...
 $ X9: num  0 0.00301 0.00183 0.0045 0.00241 ...

str(test[,1:9])
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ X1: num  0.00651 0.00286 0.00511
 $ X2: num  0.00229 0.00592 0.0031
 $ X3: num  0.00343 0.00338 0.0094
 $ X4: num  0.00464 0.00532 0.01073
 $ X5: num  0.00163 0.00203 0.01841
 $ X6: num  0.00277 0.0041 0.00865
 $ X7: num  0.00169 0.00257 0.01793
 $ X8: num  0.00669 0.00213 0.01202
 $ X9: num  0.0038 0.01023 0.00843
```

```
dimnames(train[,1:9])
[[1]]
 [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "12"  "15"  "16"  "18"  "19"  "20"  "21"  "25"  "26"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "33"  "34" 
[25] "35"  "36"  "38"  "39"  "40"  "42"  "43"  "44"  "46"  "48"  "50"  "51"  "52"  "53"  "55"  "59"  "60"  "61"  "64"  "65"  "66"  "67"  "70"  "71" 
[49] "73"  "74"  "76"  "77"  "78"  "79"  "80"  "83"  "84"  "85"  "86"  "87"  "88"  "90"  "92"  "94"  "97"  "102" "103" "104" "105" "106" "108" "109"
[73] "112" "114" "115" "116" "117"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"

dimnames(test[,1:9])
[[1]]
[1] "23" "27" "32"

[[2]]
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" "X5" "X6" "X7" "X8" "X9"
```

Comment: Hi. I have just thought of it. Here is an article how to properly visualize lime and CNN. No need to reinvent the wheel with all the preprocessing functions all by yourselves. Link: https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-03-09-lime-v04-the-kitten-picture-edition/

Comment: Very helpful, but I'm working on 1D signal not on images so I have to adapt functions to my input signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that keras model wants a matrix as an input. Or at least that was the problem with my classification. Here is what worked for me (i am assuming that your model is Sequential). Also my train data is a matrix:

```
model_type.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential <- function(x, ...) {
  "classification"
}
# Setup lime::predict_model()
predict_model.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential <- function (x, newdata, type, ...) {

  ## here you have to write function, that takes a data.frame
  ## and transform it to shape that keras understands

  ## for example if u flatten your array before training CNN, you just use
  ## as-matrix()

  ## if keras model expect 3d dataset, you write something like
  ## as.array(newdata, dims(n,12,12))

  your_function <- function(data){
  ## will return proper shape of your data
  }

  pred <- predict(object = x, x = your_function(newdata))
  data.frame (pred) }

x <- as.data.frame(train_data)  
x2 <- as.data.frame(test_data)  

explainer <- lime(x = x, model= model)



explanation <- lime::explain (
  x=  x2[1:10,], 
  explainer    = explainer, 
  n_features   = 5,
  n_labels=1) ## change for your problem    

plot_features (explanation) +
  labs (title = "LIME: Feature Importance Visualization CNN")
```

EDIT: edited answer taking into account the comment.

Comment: You are using the same data for lime and explain functions. I want to use the train set for lime function and the explain function on the test set. I am getting an error when using the flat matrix or the 3D array matrix I used for Keras functions

Comment: Ok, i changed the code, it still work locally, and I am using sequential model currently.  Your dataframes must have same structure though.

Comment: yes please, all examples I found are with MLP keras. When I am runing your code I am having a new error :  Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15000, 1900)

Comment: I have just realized your problem. Your model expect certain shape, and you need to provide preprocessing function, that will get your row in data.frame to your wanted shape. You would want something like the third commented example. iris dataset would be no good because it is 2d, mybad.